# How to restore overridden changes from previous commit in git?

Tags: git

So here's what basically happened:

1. One checks out master, branches a feature branch, makes appropriate changes (e.g. adds id attributes to xml elements) merges feature into master.
2. Someone performs a bad merge with new unrelated changes later, the changes are overridden and are now shared history
3. Some more unrelated changes are merged atop, life goes on as usual.

The question is - how do I restore changes made in p.1 without breaking stuff added in p.2 (the genuine good part) and in p.3?

Is such scenario described anywhere in Pro Git book? I can't discern it from section headers.

Comment: How much of the bad merge do you want to undo? The entire merge, or just some of the commits? Exactly how you fix this depends on what your history looks like, but it may be as simple as running `git revert c1 c2 c3`, where `c1`, `c2`, and `c3` are the bad commits introduced in step 2. (You can specify as many commits as needed as arguments to `git revert`.)

Comment: @chepner Feature branches are usually merged after squashing commits locally, so in that bad merge in p.2 could be a single commit with a lot of stuff. For sake of argument let's assume p.2 is a single commit with some positive payload. I like your suggestion though :)

Comment: You'll have to undo the bad parts by hand, since nothing in the public branch appears to record the good and bad parts separately. Start by reading the "Splitting Commits" section of `git help rebase`; you'll need that to separate the good and bad parts into separate commits if you don't still have the private feature branch available. You'll want a second branch that contains *only* the good stuff, which you can then merge into `master`, which should have the effect of undoing the bad stuff.